# Retrieving Profile Attributes on the Subscriber Object using Python API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, python

Is it possible to retrieve Profile Attributes on the Subscriber Object using Python API?

```
>>> getSub.props = ["SubscriberKey", "EmailAddress", "Status","First Name"]
>>> getSub.search_filter = {'Property' : 'SubscriberKey','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : SubscriberTestEmail}
>>> getResponse = getSub.get()                                                  >>> print 'Retrieve Status: ' + str(getResponse.status)
Retrieve Status: False
>>> getSub.search_filter = {'Property' : 'EmailAddress','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : SubscriberTestEmail}
>>> print 'Retrieve Status: ' + str(getResponse.status)                         Retrieve Status: False
>>> print 'Message: ' + str(getResponse.message)
Message: Error: The Request Property(s) First Name do not match with the fields of Subscriber retrieve
>
```

I tried both "First Name" and "Firstname", but they didn't work.

```
> >>> getSub.props = ["SubscriberKey", "EmailAddress", "Status","FirstName"]     
> >>> getSub.search_filter = {'Property' : 'EmailAddress','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' :
> SubscriberTestEmail}
> >>> getResponse = getSub.get()
> >>> print 'Retrieve Status: ' + str(getResponse.status) Retrieve Status: False
> >>> print 'Message: ' + str(getResponse.message) Message: Error: The Request Property(s) FirstName do not match with the fields of
> Subscriber retrieve
```

I am new to programming and API. It seems like it's possible with .net or php. Which language is better to learn and use for ET's API?

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_profile_attributes_on_the_subscriber_object/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ID` to getSub.props.

```
getSub.props = ["SubscriberKey", "EmailAddress", "Status","First Name", "ID"]
```

This isn't documented well and this question comes up a lot on this site.

Related: [How to retrieve Subscriber Profile Attributes using RetrieveRequest using AMPscript (Landing Page)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77087/how-to-retrieve-subscriber-profile-attributes-using-retrieverequest-using-ampscr/77100#77100)